# How to match data between columns to do the comparasion

Tags: excel, vba

I do not really know how to explain this in a clear manner. Please see attached image

[image]

I have a table with 4 different columns, 2 are identical to each other (NAME and QTY). The goal is to compare the differences between the QTY, however, in order to do it. I must:
1. sort the data
2. match the data item by item
This is not a big deal with small table but with 10 thousand rows, it takes me a few days to do it.

Pleas help me, I appreciate.

My logic is:
1. Sorted the first two columns (NAME and QTY)
2. For each value of second two columns (NAME and QTY), check if it match with first two column. If true, the insert the value.
3. For values are not matched, insert to new rows with offset from the rows that are in first two columns but not in second two columns

Comment: In your example, why is `XX` in your first 2 columns sorted before `BB1` in your 2nd 2 columns?  Is that a typo or expected behavior?

Comment: Thank you for asking. It is a typo, but actually it is not important. As long as the matched rows for the ones that match, and the ones that do not match must be stand alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Based on your above requirements, the logic totally changes and hence I am posting it as a different answer.

Also in your "**This is Wonderful**" snapshot above, there is a slight error. As per logic `SAMPLE10` cannot come above `SAMPLE11`. It has to come after `SAMPLE11`.

See the below snapshot

[image]

And here is the code :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub sAMPLE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, newRow As Long, rw As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, SrchRange As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Columns("A:B").Copy .Columns("G:G")
         .Columns("G:H").Sort key1:=.Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
          DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        .Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

         lastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

         For i = 2 To lastRow
            .Range("H" & i).Value = GetLastNumbers(.Range("G" & i).Value)

            If .Range("H" & i).Value <> 0 Then
                .Range("G" & i).Value = Left(.Range("G" & i).Value, _
                Len(.Range("G" & i).Value) - Len(.Range("H" & i).Value))
            End If
         Next i

        .Columns("G:H").Sort key1:=.Range("H2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Range("H" & i).Value <> 0 Then _
            .Range("G" & i).Value = .Range("G" & i).Value & .Range("H" & i).Value
        Next i

        .Columns("H:H").Delete

        newRow = lastRow

        Set SrchRange = .Range("G2:G" & lastRow)

        lastRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("I1").Value = "NAME": .Range("J1").Value = "QTY"

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("C" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                Set aCell = SrchRange.Find(What:=.Range("C" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    .Range("I" & aCell.Row).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                    .Range("J" & aCell.Row).Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C" & lastRow _
                            & "=" & """" & .Range("C" & i).Value & """" & ")*(D2:D" & lastRow & "))")
                Else
                    newRow = newRow + 1
                    .Range("I" & newRow).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                    .Range("J" & newRow).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
        lastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("G" & i).Value = .Range("G" & i - 1).Value Then
                .Range("H" & i - 1).Value = .Range("H" & i).Value + .Range("H" & i - 1).Value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("I" & i & ":J" & i)) = 0 Then
                    .Range("G" & i & ":J" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                Else
                    .Range("G" & i & ":H" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        lastRow = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        newRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If lastRow <= newRow Then Exit Sub

        .Range("I" & newRow & ":J" & lastRow).Sort key1:=.Range("I" & newRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        For i = lastRow To newRow Step -1
            If .Range("I" & i).Value = .Range("I" & i - 1).Value Then
                .Range("J" & i - 1).Value = .Range("J" & i).Value + .Range("J" & i - 1).Value
                .Range("I" & i & ":J" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function GetLastNumbers(strVal As String) As Long
    Dim j As Long, strTemp As String

    For j = Len(strVal) To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(strVal, j, 1)) Then Exit For
        strTemp = Mid(strVal, j, 1) & strTemp
    Next j
    GetLastNumbers = Val(Trim(strTemp))
End Function
```

Comment: Rout, thank you very much - this is the very complicated code - I wish I could understand all.

Comment: :) for some reason, if I have several rows with SAMPLE11 QTY=100, on column 3 and 4 - then the sum(SAMPLE11) is not correct.

Comment: Here is the result, should be 602 but it is 107 http://i50.tinypic.com/2qlqzp3.jpg. Thank you very much for helping me alot

Comment: Code Updated. Please test it now.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, newRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, SrchRange As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Columns("A:B").Copy .Columns("G:G")
        .Columns("G:H").Sort Key1:=.Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
          DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        lastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        newRow = lastRow

        Set SrchRange = .Range("G2:G" & lastRow)

        lastRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("I1").Value = "NAME": .Range("J1").Value = "QTY"

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("C" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                Set aCell = SrchRange.Find(What:=.Range("C" & i).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    .Range("I" & aCell.Row).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                    .Range("J" & aCell.Row).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
                Else
                    newRow = newRow + 1
                    .Range("I" & newRow).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                    .Range("J" & newRow).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I am looking for. I have a small concern, it is possible if I highlight/selected a 4 columns (still together but stand in different column's name for example instead of A,B,C,D===> G,H,I,J, they can be E,F,G,H===>K,L,M,N. started in different columns but still get the similar result?

Comment: Yup :) You can change that in the code :) Replace A:B by E:F and so on :)

Comment: Thank you :) I will try my best. Today is the first day I start to learn VBA in Excel.

Comment: @SiddhartRout, I ran into a little bit problem today.  If the second data (column 3 and 4) have repeated values, then the program will not do the compare perfectly.  Any chance to fix this?

Comment: Remove duplicates at the end of the code by using this `Range("$I$1:$I$13").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header :=xlYes` I have hardcoded `$I$1:$I$13` you can always get the realistic end row and amend the same :)

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth, remove duplicate it will not serve my purpose.  The purpose is to compare the quality for matching items. If I remove duplicate, then the there will be loss in data (aka: duplicated ones). For example if in column C, D I have multiple BB2 QTY=1, BB2, QTY= 2, BB2 QTY=3. Removing duplicated ones will make QTY=2, and 3 disappear.

Comment: I actually meant `$I$1:$J$13` No remove duplicates won't remove these kind of values. BTW how would you like to display them? If you can show a sample data and it would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/dtnk9.jpg - in example you can see that SAMPLE11 are repeated 2 times on both list.  Either result 1 or result 2 is good but if it can auto merge, then it is better.

Comment: How did you arrive at SAMPLE11 in Col F Twice? Also as per the original logic where did the quantity come from in Col I for SAMPLE11?

Comment: Ops - wrong one. http://i50.tinypic.com/el48ao.jpg sorry for the confusion.  I mean if there is no repeated PN then everything is fine. However, if there are, you can see in the current result, only one SAMPLE11 appears (QTY is 1)

Comment: Everything is working well until today I figured out the result off, then because on the column 3 and 4 of the result, it does not take account of repeated values.

Comment: Based on your above requirements, the logic totally changes and hence I am posting it as a different answer.